# How to fetch data as association array like pg_fetch_assoc in laravel controller?

Tags: laravel, associative-array

When I'm using pg_fetch_assoc then my output like below

```
[{"0":"T","id":"I","1":"T-ABC"},
{"0":"T","id":"I","1":"T-XYZ"},
{"0":"T","id":"I","1":"T-QWR"}]
```

But right now I'm using Laravel framework and in my controller am using below code

```
$type=$request->type;
$query= typeModel::get()->where('id',$type);
return response()->json($query);
```

> The above code is give me below format

```
{"11":{"id":"I","type":"T-ABC"},
"12":{"id":"I","type":"T-XYZ"},
"13":{"id":"I","type":"T-OWR"}}
```

> But I need format like pg_fetch_assoc How can i achieve this in
>   laravel

Comment: Is it really return all `"id": "I"` when you using `pg_fetch_assoc`

Comment: yes its a dummy data just for an example

Comment: is there any way to fetch associate array instead of object in laravel?

Comment: I not really understand, because your first example results' key is `'0','id', '1'`, and have `"id": "I"`; however, the second results for laravel is `"id": "T"` without "I", I don't know the relationship between them.

Comment: Please check again i edit the question both are I

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using eloquent collection method `map()` to map every stdClass;

Because `pg_fetch_assoc` return the **column name**, **column value**, **index key** and **index value**;

So we can use `array_merge` to merge two array.

The one is `$array1` including **column name**, **column value**;

The other one is `$array2` only have all the **column value**;

**Convert array to stdClass**, it will automatically add index key on that `$array2`, and this index key is start from `0`:

```php
$query = typeModel::where('id',$type)->get()->map(function($item) {
         $array1 = $item->toarray();
         $array2 = array_values($array1);
         return (object) array_merge($array1, $array2);
    })->toArray();
```

Comment: Its give me [{"0":"T-ABC","1":" Institues","id":"I"},
{"0":"T-XYZ","1":"Institues","id":"I"},
{"0":"T-QWR","1":"Institues","id":"I"}]

Comment: But i need like [{"0":"I","id":"I","1":"T-ABC","type":"T-ABC","2":"Institues","type_desc":"Institues"},
{"0":"I","id":"I","1":"T-XYZ","type":"T-XYZ","2":"Institues","type_desc":"Institues"},
{"0":"I","id":"I","1":"T-QWR","type":"T-QWR","2":"Institues","type_desc":"Institues"}]

Comment: Means fetch column name and array both for example in 0 elment its show I and alos column name "id" I

Comment: can you please explain your code so that i can understand how its works